# python if clause won't activate

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm writing a program to find a missing digit in an ISBN number. you have to find the remainder with 11 of the first 9 numbers multiplied like this: first*10,  second number *9, third * 8, etcetera. If this remainder equals the 10th digit, the ISBN is correct.

I have some code that puts a zero in the space of the question mark, and finds the index in the number where the zero was, and adds 1*the index to the total, and mods it by 11. Then, if the remainder of that with 11 did not equal the 10th digit, it tries 2* the index, and keeps going until it finds the right number. However, the block of code that does this final part is not triggering, and i cannot figure out why.

```
def calculate_missing(x):
    tally=1
    for item in x:
        if item=='?':
            break
        elif item!='?':
            tally+=1
    if tally==10:
        without=str(x).replace('?','')
        if isbncalculate(without)==10:
            return 'x'
        elif isbncalculate(without)==11:
            return '0'
        else:
            return isbncalculate(without)
        #these just find the missing digit if it is the final digit.
    multiply=11-tally
    x=x.replace('?','0')
    lastdig=x[9]
    x=x.replace(x[9],'')
    time=10
    newnum=0
    for item in str(x):
        item=int(item)
        item*=time
        newnum+=int(item)
        time-=1
    otherthing=6
    if lastdig=='x' or lastdig=='X':
        lastdig=10
    elif lastdig=='0':
        lastdig='11'
    final=newnum+(otherthing*multiply)
    answer=final%11
    for item in range(0,10):
        if answer==lastdig:
            #this code won't trigger!
            return otherthing
        else:
            otherthing+=1
```

the last few lines are the ones I am struggling with. If I input `calculate_missing('567?545653')` , it should return 6, but instead it just returns nothing.

Comment: Is that the actual indentation you're using? Because posting python code with the wrong indentation is really unhelpful

Comment: With how your code is currently formatted, `answer`, `otherthing`, and `lastdig` all remain constant for the entire duration of the for loop, meaning the result will never change!

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense - why loop over `item`? If `answer != lastdig` on the first iteration, it won't be on any subsequent iteration either.

Comment: nchecn24- really? how do i fix that? I thought that since they were outside of the loop they could change.

Comment: jonrsharpe- part of answer is otherthing*multiply, and otherthing changes each iteration. I think I have gotten the indentation wrong though.

Comment: could you also post the code for isbncalculate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
if answer==lastdig:
```

with:

```
if answer==int(lastdig):
```

The thing is even though both `answer` and `lastdig` are equal but `answer` is an **integer** and `lastdig` is a **string**. So, either convert `answer` to **string** while comparision or `lastdig` to **integer**. This will fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks so much! It was so simple, i cant believe it caused me all this trouble!

Comment: I changed otherthing back to 0, and it now has stopped giving me a result. Have i messed it up?

Comment: however, im still having a strange issue. I tried it with a new isbn,2343234322, and i got this when trying it with a question mark in different places:

Comment: >>>calculate_missing('2343?34322')
>>> calculate_missing('2?43234322')
4
one did not give an answer, and the other gave an incorrect one. pretty confused now!